# Adding href links inside <span class = | AND Is it possible to do that?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a line of  code like this and I want to include the href element or anything applicable link element into each of the words ( achievable, lovely, fancy, beautiful, etc.. ) without changing the any styles and spacing of the words.

Ex: link: amazon.com

```js
var words = document.getElementsByClassName('word');
var wordArray = [];
var currentWord = 0;

words[currentWord].style.opacity = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  splitLetters(words[i]);
}

function changeWord() {
  var cw = wordArray[currentWord];
  var nw = currentWord == words.length-1 ? wordArray[0] : wordArray[currentWord+1];
  for (var i = 0; i < cw.length; i++) {
    animateLetterOut(cw, i);
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < nw.length; i++) {
    nw[i].className = 'letter behind';
    nw[0].parentElement.style.opacity = 1;
    animateLetterIn(nw, i);
  }
  
  currentWord = (currentWord == wordArray.length-1) ? 0 : currentWord+1;
}

function animateLetterOut(cw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
        cw[i].className = 'letter out';
  }, i*80);
}

function animateLetterIn(nw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
        nw[i].className = 'letter in';
  }, 340+(i*80));
}

function splitLetters(word) {
  var content = word.innerHTML;
  word.innerHTML = '';
  var letters = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    var letter = document.createElement('span');
    letter.className = 'letter';
    letter.innerHTML = content.charAt(i);
    word.appendChild(letter);
    letters.push(letter);
  }
  
  wordArray.push(letters);
}

changeWord();
setInterval(changeWord, 4000);

// // I DO NOT OWN THIS. I TAKE THIS COMPLETELY FROM SOMEONE AS A PRACTICE. PLEASE THE OWNER, IF YOU WANT TO TAKE DOWN THIS, CONTACT ME AND I WILL TAKE IT DOWN IMMEDIATELY. THANK YOU VERY MUCH //
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 450px;
  left:45%;
  margin-left: -225px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 25%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  color: antiquewhite;
 
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
}

.word {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.letter {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  transform: translateZ(25px);
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 25px;
}

.letter.out {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transition: transform 0.32s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.letter.behind {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}

.letter.in {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.38s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.wisteria {
  color: #8e44ad;
}

.belize {
  color: #2980b9;
}

.pomegranate {
  color: #c0392b;
}

.green {
  color: #16a085;
}

.midnight {
  color: #007bf7;
}

.pomegranate {
  color: #c0392b;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>by Nguyên Phùng</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
</head>
</head>
<style>
body {
  background-image: url("Dark 5K.jpg");
  background-position: center;
}
button{
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgb(207, 207, 207);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="text">
  <p>Your dreams are</p>
  <p>
    <span class="word wisteria">achievable</span></a>
    <span class="word belize">lovely.</span></a>
    <span class="word pomegranate">fancy.</span>
    <span class="word green">beautiful.</span>
    <span class="word midnight">realistic.</span>
    <span class="word midnight">strong.</span>

  </p>
</div>
  <script  src="./script.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try Considering This One:

Probably Might Help You.

```html
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>by Nguyên Phùng</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
</head>
</head>
<style>
body {
  background-image: url("Dark 5K.jpg");
  background-position: center;
}
button{
  border: none;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgb(207, 207, 207);
}
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  width: 450px;
  left:45%;
  margin-left: -225px;
  height: 40px;
  top: 25%;
  margin-top: -20px;
  color: antiquewhite;
 
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
}

.word {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.letter {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  transform: translateZ(25px);
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 25px;
}

.letter.out {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transition: transform 0.32s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.letter.behind {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}

.letter.in {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.38s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.wisteria {
  color: #8e44ad;
}

.belize {
  color: #2980b9;
}

.pomegranate {
  color: #c0392b;
}

.green {
  color: #16a085;
}

.midnight {
  color: #007bf7;
}

.pomegranate {
  color: #c0392b;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="text">
  <p>Your dreams are</p>
  <p>
    <a href="https://www.amazon.in"><span class="word wisteria">achievable</span></a>
    <a href="https://www.amazon.in"><span class="word belize">lovely.</span></a>
    <a href="https://www.amazon.in"><span class="word pomegranate">fancy.</span></a>
    <a href="https://www.amazon.in"><span class="word green">beautiful.</span></a>
    <a href="https://www.amazon.in"><span class="word midnight">realistic.</span></a>
    <a href="https://www.amazon.in"><span class="word midnight">strong.</span></a>

  </p>
</div>
  <script  src="./script.js"></script>
 </body>
 <script>
  var words = document.getElementsByClassName('word');
var wordArray = [];
var currentWord = 0;

words[currentWord].style.opacity = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  splitLetters(words[i]);
}

function changeWord() {
  var cw = wordArray[currentWord];
  var nw = currentWord == words.length-1 ? wordArray[0] : wordArray[currentWord+1];
  for (var i = 0; i < cw.length; i++) {
    animateLetterOut(cw, i);
  }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < nw.length; i++) {
    nw[i].className = 'letter behind';
    nw[0].parentElement.style.opacity = 1;
    animateLetterIn(nw, i);
  }
  
  currentWord = (currentWord == wordArray.length-1) ? 0 : currentWord+1;
}

function animateLetterOut(cw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
        cw[i].className = 'letter out';
  }, i*80);
}

function animateLetterIn(nw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
        nw[i].className = 'letter in';
  }, 340+(i*80));
}

function splitLetters(word) {
  var content = word.innerHTML;
  word.innerHTML = '';
  var letters = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    var letter = document.createElement('span');
    letter.className = 'letter';
    letter.innerHTML = content.charAt(i);
    word.appendChild(letter);
    letters.push(letter);
  }
  
  wordArray.push(letters);
}

changeWord();
setInterval(changeWord, 4000);
</script>
 </html>
```

Comment: run it in your browser to see accurate results

Comment: Oh I am so sorry. I forgot to add the rest of the code, including the CSS and JS. Can you please help me again ? I tried your code in the html but it won't work. Thank you so much :3

Comment: does my solution helps you, let me know. again run it in your browser to see accurate results

Comment: let me know if you find it helpful

Comment: Could you explain a bit what your solution is, not just give the code.

Comment: @Yashchitroda I tested your code and it worked flawlessly. Thank you so much. May I ask for your explanation about your solution please. That would be a lot appreciate. Have a nice day.

Comment: You just need to add anchor tag before span tag
Thanks for feedback

Answer (score 0):

You can't just convert each of the spans around the words into a elements given the way the HTML is structured as it will always be the last word ('strong.' in this case) whose href will be picked up.

Instead, and so as to alter the rest of the code as little as possible, this snippet puts the whole set of words into an anchor element. Its href is updated when a new word is selected with the href for that word. The standard HTML way of adding data related to an element is to use the data- attribute and in this case we call it data-href. On selecting a new word the href for it is found and copied into the href for the anchor tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>by Nguyên Phùng</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>
</head>
<style>
  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);
  body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 50px;
  }
  
  .text {
    position: absolute;
    width: 450px;
    left: 45%;
    margin-left: -225px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 25%;
    margin-top: -20px;
    color: antiquewhite;
  }
  
  p {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .word {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  .letter {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    transform: translateZ(25px);
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 25px;
  }
  
  .letter.out {
    transform: rotateX(90deg);
    transition: transform 0.32s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
  }
  
  .letter.behind {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  }
  
  .letter.in {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
    transition: transform 0.38s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
  }
  
  .wisteria {
    color: #8e44ad;
  }
  
  .belize {
    color: #2980b9;
  }
  
  .pomegranate {
    color: #c0392b;
  }
  
  .green {
    color: #16a085;
  }
  
  .midnight {
    color: #007bf7;
  }
  
  .pomegranate {
    color: #c0392b;
  }
  
  body {
    background-image: url("Dark 5K.jpg");
    background-position: center;
  }
  
  button {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgb(207, 207, 207);
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
  <div class="text">
    <p>Your dreams are</p>
    <p>
      <a id="gotohref" href="">
        <span class="word wisteria" data-href="https://google.com">achievable</span>
        <span class="word belize" data-href="https://microsoft.com">lovely.</span>
        <span class="word pomegranate" data-href="https://apple.com">fancy.</span>
        <span class="word green" data-href="https://twitter.com">beautiful.</span>
        <span class="word midnight" data-href="https://facebook.com">realistic.</span>
        <span class="word midnight" data-href="https://stackoverflow.com">strong.</span>
      </a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <script>
    const gotohref = document.getElementById('gotohref');
    const spans = gotohref.children;
    var words = document.getElementsByClassName('word');
    var wordArray = [];
    var currentWord = 0;

    words[currentWord].style.opacity = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      splitLetters(words[i]);
    }

    function changeWord() {
      var cw = wordArray[currentWord];
      var nw = currentWord == words.length - 1 ? wordArray[0] : wordArray[currentWord + 1];
      for (var i = 0; i < cw.length; i++) {
        animateLetterOut(cw, i);
      }

      for (var i = 0; i < nw.length; i++) {
        nw[i].className = 'letter behind';
        nw[0].parentElement.style.opacity = 1;
        animateLetterIn(nw, i);
      }

      currentWord = (currentWord == wordArray.length - 1) ? 0 : currentWord + 1;

      //now make the href in the anchor element equal to the one for the current word
      gotohref.href = spans[currentWord].getAttribute('data-href');

    }

    function animateLetterOut(cw, i) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        cw[i].className = 'letter out';
      }, i * 80);
    }

    function animateLetterIn(nw, i) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        nw[i].className = 'letter in';
      }, 340 + (i * 80));
    }

    function splitLetters(word) {
      var content = word.innerHTML;
      word.innerHTML = '';
      var letters = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
        var letter = document.createElement('span');
        letter.className = 'letter';
        letter.innerHTML = content.charAt(i);
        word.appendChild(letter);
        letters.push(letter);
      }

      wordArray.push(letters);
    }

    changeWord();
    setInterval(changeWord, 4000);

    // // I DO NOT OWN THIS. I TAKE THIS COMPLETELY FROM SOMEONE AS A PRACTICE. PLEASE THE OWNER, IF YOU WANT TO TAKE DOWN THIS, CONTACT ME AND I WILL TAKE IT DOWN IMMEDIATELY. THANK YOU VERY MUCH //
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hello A Haworth, I tested your code but it didn't work in VSC. I think probably the <a id="gotohref" conflict with the rest of codes. It won't direct me to the site, but instead conflict with the rest of my code in VSC. Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciated it though. Have a nice day, A Haworth. –